# How i can filter in featherjs?

Tags: javascript, feathersjs, nedb

I'm trying to filter database with nedb in feather js.

I'm using this command but it doesn't work.

I'm using this command but it doesn't work.

```
const NeDB = require('nedb');
const feathers = require('feathers');
const rest = require('feathers-rest');
const socketio = require('feathers-socketio');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const errors = require('feathers-errors');
const service = require('feathers-nedb');

const db = new NeDB({
  filename: './db-data/messages',
  autoload: true
});

// Create a feathers instance.
var app = feathers()
  // Enable REST services
  .configure(rest())
  // Enable Socket.io services
  .configure(socketio())
  // Turn on JSON parser for REST services
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  // Turn on URL-encoded parser for REST services
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));

// Connect to the db, create and register a Feathers service.


// Set the `paginate` option during initialization


app.use('/messages', service({
  Model: db,
}));


app.service('messages').find({

  query: {

    $skip: 5,
    $limit: 2
  }
});



// Create a dummy Message
app.service('messages').create({
  text: 'Oh hai!'
}).then(function(message) {
  console.log('Created message', message);
});



// Start the server.
const port = 3030;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Feathers server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

not get filter

please help me

not get filter

please help me

Comment: Does it give any error?

Comment: not filter the messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). To get the result of the promise register a callback in `.then`:

```
app.service('messages').find({
  query: {

    $skip: 5,
    $limit: 2
  }
})
.then(messages => {
  console.log('Found messages', messages);
});
```

Comment: hi very thank you but you can help me how put the console log into a variable for reuse this output  message

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "," that you have after the "db" on this line:

```
app.use('/messages', service({  Model: db,}));
```

Comment: which  , comma?   .

Comment: this one: 
app.use('/messages', service({  Model: db,}));

Comment: i remove but not filter

Comment: i start to see any changes

Comment: i see the problem i dont create a text after filter